# Need suggestion with a for loop for postgres code

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to write a postgres query to fetch cluster id's for a beta_plan_id and do some operation later.. for a single beta_plan_id in the below table there may be many merch id and so many cluster_id. how will this be handled??

```
BETA_PLAN_ID  MERCH_LEVEL1_ID    BETA_PLAN_MERCH_LVL1_CLSTR_ID    NO_OF_STORES
1                    1                 12                           5,6,7
1                    1                 13                            9,10
1                    1                 14                           2,3,4
2                    2                 15                            13,12

SELECT BETA_PLAN_MERCH_LVL1_CLSTR_ID INTO i_clstr_id 
FROM beta_plan.BETA_PLAN_MERCH_LVL1_CLSTR 
WHERE BETA_PLAN_ID = in_beta_plan_id;
```

the problem is many results will be returned since BETA_PLAN_MERCH_LVL1_CLSTR_ID is a serial type and uniquely generated for (beta_plan_id, merch_id,cluster_id) combo.

```
SELECT BETA_PLAN_MERCH_LVL1_CLSTR_ID 
   INTO i_clstr_id 
   FROM beta_plan.BETA_PLAN_MERCH_LVL1_CLSTR 
   WHERE BETA_PLAN_ID = in_beta_plan_id;

INSERT INTO beta_plan.BETA_PLAN_MERCH_LVL1_CLSTR
   (
       BETA_PLAN_ID,
       MERCH_LEVEL1_ID,
       CLUSTER_ID,
       CLUSTER_NAME,
       NO_OF_STORES,
       NO_OF_FOOTAGE_VARIATION,
       CREATED_USER,
       CREATED_TS
   )
   SELECT 
      out_plan_id,
      merch_lvl1_clstr.MERCH_LEVEL1_ID,
      merch_lvl1_clstr.CLUSTER_ID,
      merch_lvl1_clstr.CLUSTER_NAME,
      merch_lvl1_clstr.NO_OF_STORES,
      merch_lvl1_clstr.NO_OF_FOOTAGE_VARIATION
      in_user_id, 
      now()
   FROM beta_plan.BETA_PLAN_MERCH_LVL1_CLSTR merch_lvl1_clstr
      INNER JOIN beta_plan.BETA_PLAN_MERCH_COPY_PLAN merch_copy
         ON merch_copy.MERCH_ID = merch_lvl1_clstr.MERCH_LEVEL1_ID
            AND merch_lvl1_clstr.BETA_PLAN_ID = in_beta_plan_id
   RETURNING BETA_PLAN_MERCH_LVL1_CLSTR_ID INTO o_clstr_id;

INSERT INTO beta_plan.BETA_PLAN_MERCH_LVL1_CLSTR_STR
   (
      BETA_PLAN_MERCH_LVL1_CLSTR_ID,
      STORE_ID,
      CREATED_USER,
      CREATED_TS         
   )
   SELECT 
      o_clstr_id,
      STORE_ID,     
      in_user_id, 
      now()
   FROM beta_plan.BETA_PLAN_MERCH_LVL1_CLSTR_STR
   WHERE BETA_PLAN_MERCH_LVL1_CLSTR_ID = i_clstr_id;
```

Comment: Which of the `BETA_PLAN_MERCH_LVL1_CLSTR_ID` do you want returned for a given `BETA_PLAN_ID`?

Comment: I need the rows for beta_plan_id 1 which has cluster_id's 12,13,14.. I need to insert these id's and corresponding store_id's above in clstr_str table..So basically i need a select statement loop through the records and insert in the clstr_str table finally.

Comment: In a PostgreSQL function or in a programming lamguage on the database client?

Comment: In a PostgresSQL function Laurenz..I have the below code now which works perfectly if there is only one cluster_id for beta_plan_id..i need a solution on how to handle multiple cluster_id's and respective store_id's for a single beta_plan_id..

Comment: INNER JOIN beta_plan.BETA_PLAN_MERCH_COPY_PLAN merch_copy ON merch_copy.MERCH_ID = merch_lvl1_clstr.MERCH_LEVEL1_ID AND merch_lvl1_clstr.BETA_PLAN_ID    = in_beta_plan_id
 RETURNING BETA_PLAN_MERCH_LVL1_CLSTR_ID into o_clstr_id; 

INSERT INTO beta_plan.BETA_PLAN_MERCH_LVL1_CLSTR_STR
          (   BETA_PLAN_MERCH_LVL1_CLSTR_ID,STORE_ID,CREATED_USER, CREATED_TS )
   SELECT o_clstr_id,STORE_IDiin_user_id, now() FROM beta_plan.BETA_PLAN_MERCH_LVL1_CLSTR_STR  WHERE BETA_PLAN_MERCH_LVL1_CLSTR_ID = i_clstr_id;

Comment: @vigneshramanathan Please click [edit] under the question to add samples of your existing code; comments don't really work well for long pieces of code, as you can see, and we like to have all the important information in the main question area.

Comment: Apologize, I have added the sample in the question section.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the first `SELECT` statement, use a `FOR` loop that encloses the other statements:

```
FOR i_clstr_id IN
   SELECT BETA_PLAN_MERCH_LVL1_CLSTR_ID 
   FROM beta_plan.BETA_PLAN_MERCH_LVL1_CLSTR 
   WHERE BETA_PLAN_ID = in_beta_plan_id
LOOP
   /* your two INSERT statements come here */
END LOOP;
```

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) for details.